# How to format a Javascript object as a polygon in Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, polygon

I want to store a Javascript object as a polygon in a Mysql database.
I can define start and end points of x and y to give me four corners:

```
var polygon = [
    xstart +' '+ ystart,
    xend +' '+ ystart,
    xend +' '+ yend,
    xstart +' '+ yend,
    xstart +' '+ ystart
];
```

I can format this object as a string

```
polygon = "ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(("+ polygon.toString() +"))'";
```

When I insert this into a Mysql database

```
INSERT INTO `caption` (`caption_id`, `caption_area`) VALUES (NULL, '\'POLYGON((0.28 0.33,0.35 0.33,0.35 0.45,0.28 0.45,0.28 0.33))\'')
```

the query fails

```
#1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

How can I format the Javascript object, or the query, to correctly insert a polygon in to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql you must use [ST_GeomFromText](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html)

```
polygon = "ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON("+ polygon.toString() +")')";
```

I am unsure what you need the number 0 at the end.

Comment: The query still fails. I updated my question to include your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: That because us have a string the instead of a code, so show please wheerer you build your query it has to look like INSERT INTO `caption` (`caption_id`, `caption_area`) VALUES (NULL, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0.28 0.33,0.35 0.33,0.35 0.45,0.28 0.45,0.28 0.33')))

Comment: You are correct. The query still fails because I was using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

POLYGON is a Spatial Data Type from MySQL spatial extension defined in the Open Geospatial Consortium OpenGIS.
You can define a Spatial Data Type in MySQL for your four polygon. The following is an example using LINESTRING:

```
    LINESTRING(0.28540775806607094 0.3356063323928521, 0.35407728596306665      0.3356063323928521, 0.35407728596306665 0.45764498813705906, 0.28540775806607094 0.45764498813705906, 0.28540775806607094 0.3356063323928521)
```

So, it stores caption_area as TEXT using:

```
    SET @g = 'LINESTRING(0.28540775806607094 0.3356063323928521, 0.35407728596306665 0.3356063323928521, 0.35407728596306665 0.45764498813705906, 0.28540775806607094 0.45764498813705906, 0.28540775806607094 0.3356063323928521)';

    INTO `caption` (`caption_id`, `caption_area`) VALUES (NULL,ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromText(@g)));
```

Also, an example with POLYGON:

```
    SET @g = 'POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0),(5 5,7 5,7 7,5 7, 5 5))';
    INTO `caption` (`caption_id`, `caption_area`)
    VALUES  (NULL,ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromText(@g)));
```

Comment: I would like to store a polygon rather than a linestring.